# Travelling to Pakistan with one month passport validity

Tags: pakistani-citizens, visa-expiration, pakistan

I am scheduled to travel from the UK to Pakistan in two days and I just realised that my passport is due to expire on 06 May 2023, which is only one month from my travel date. I also have a NiCOP (National Identity Card for Overseas Pakistani) which is valid until 2031. Therefore, I won't have any issues entering Pakistan, but I am concerned about whether I will be allowed to board the flight since my passport only has one month of validity left. Generally, the rule is that a passport should be valid for six months from the date of departure or arrival in some cases. So, the question is, can I travel to Pakistan, as a Pakistani national with a valid NiCOP, but with only one month of validity left on my passport?

I have contacted the Pakistani Embassy and, as expected, I did not receive clear information. According to them, it's up to the airline or immigration authorities to decide whether to allow me to travel with only one month of validity remaining on my Pakistani passport. They confirmed that Pakistan has no issue with me travelling or entering the country as my passport is still valid. However, they couldn't provide me with anything in writing to present to the UK immigration authorities or the airline. The six-month passport validity rule is an international regulation, but it's not a requirement in every country.

Comment: Do you have a direct flight or do you have to change planes somewhere and if so, is it on one ticket?

Comment: The Pakistan Embassy is correct. Whether the airline permits you to board will depend on your itinerary and carrier(s). There is no "international rule" about 6-month validity, although some countries require it.

Comment: I am flying with Qatar Airways. So change at Doha. But its on one single ticket. Not separate two tickets.

Comment: Thanks David. I am British national and so are my children. Its only my wife who is on spouse visa holding Pakistan nationality. So are you saying I can still argue and try as her passport is still valid for one month? Or shall I just leave it and not take a chance as I may lose the whole ticket in thsi way

Comment: The board/no board decision as to one traveler will not affect whether the other travelers can board. The risk of refusal, of course, is that if your wife were denied boarding, the rest of your traveling group would fly and she would be left behind at the departure airport. You can certainly **discuss** and **reason** and **plead** with the agent, and the agent's superior, but I would avoid **arguing**.

Comment: @WaleedKhalid, can you please provide an update on whether or not you had an issues? I am traveling with a NICOP and a US passport that will be a few days shy of 6-month validity. Technically speaking, a NICOP certifies that I am a Pakistani citizen and that should be enough for the airline. But I know that in these circumstances you are at the mercy of the airline employees...